# Should a stove flue be grounded for lightning protection?

Tags: grounding, chimney, woodstove

I have a freestanding wood burning stove that has a metal flue straight up through to the roof.  The existing stone chimney with aerials is taller than the new flue (see pic).

Should there be an earthing system in place for the flue - more specifically to mitigate potential effects of a lightning strike?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lightning protection system is a building wide system.

You don't just protect things individually.

The ridgeline of your house would get air terminals and then if the antenna and chimney are within the "zone of influence" (lightning protection term) they would be bonded to the system.

If your house is less than 50' tall and you are not in an extremely high strike area (central Florida), I wouldn't bother. Usually very tall barns are the only residential buildings that get lightning protection.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for answering, it was more out of curiosity as the installer never mentioned it and I forgot to ask.  We're in the UK and only occasionally get lightning.

Comment: "Usually very tall barns are the only residential buildings that get lightning protection." - What about [tv antennas](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/should-i-ground-my-tv-antenna)?  Why ground a tv antenna and not a stove pipe?  Is it because the tv antenna connects to your house's electrical circuits?

Answer (score 0):

All metal pipes/structures above the roof line must be earthed or grounded. It makes no sense to only ground high buildings. Here in South Africa where I live, we get lightning storms nearly every day in summer and many people with single story houses have been hit hard by these bolts, whereas high structures and trees stood next to these houses.  In essence - the lowest parts were hit not the high structures. Lightning can strike anywhere at anytime.

Comment: Thanks for specifying your locale. While your information is valid, "must" doesn't _legally_ apply everywhere. It is probably practical advice for most, though.