# Grounding a roof mounted TV antenna

Tags: television, tv-antenna

Can I use a single common 10AWG wire to simultaneously ground both the coax cable and the mast by running a short jumper between the coax grounding block and the mast?  Or should I use two separate wires, both run all the way to the in ground rod??

Comment: That is not grounding, that would be a lightening rood, look it up

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I ground my TV antenna?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/should-i-ground-my-tv-antenna)

Comment: This question asks about using a single wire for grounding 2 things. The other question asks whether the antenna should be grounded. Not the same thing. This question appears to assume that the antenna will be grounded.

Comment: @RohitGupta There looks like plenty of answer in there to me to both the questions in this one.